# How can we determine if two vectors are parallel?

Tags: calculus, orthogonality, cross-product

What are the minimal number of products like dot cross that can give us information if two vectors are parallel ?

What can we say if V*W = 1 assuming V and W are not unit vectors.

Comment: Are you talking about 3-dimensional space (where cross-product applies) or more general spaces?

Answer (score 5):

So the cross product of two vectors is actually enough. $|V \times W| = 0$ is the condition you want, for the equality $|V \times W| = |V|\cdot |W|\cdot Sin(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle between V and W tells you that they are parallel.

Comment: By the way, the proof of the identity I used is not too hard and is in a lot of Multivariable Calculus books, I'm sure Stewart has it in the Appendix if not the main text. It's worth looking at, if you're interested in this kind of thing, and I think the book Elementary Differential Geometry by O'Neill goes into a lot of depth on related subjects.

Answer (score 2):

Using Cauchy-Schwarz (assuming we are talking about a Hilbert space, etc...) , $(V\cdot W)^2=V^2W^2$ iff $V$ and $W$ are parallel. I count 3 dot products, so the solution involving 1 cross product is more efficient in this sense, but the cross product is a bit more involved.

If $(V\cdot W)=1$ (my interpretation of your question) and $V^2,W^2\ne1$, then at least one of them has to have norm greater than 1. They could be non parallel or parallel though. But if you require that $V^2,W^2>1$, then they are definitely non-parallel.